# unable to dispaly polygon on the map using Leaflet draw plugin

Tags: leaflet, display, polygons, leaflet.draw

I am trying to use draw plugin from  here http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw

and tried using it locally as shown below

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <style>
        #map{ height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

   var  drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw : {
            position : 'topleft',
            polygon : true,
            polyline : false,
            rectangle : true,
            circle : false

        },
        edit : false
    });

    map.addControl(drawControl);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the drawing control and map but the polygon draw is not shown up after drawing is completed not sure how to do it

Please help in getting the polygon drawn on the map as shown in this demo

```
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a feature group and add the layers when they are created ...

```
   var drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

   map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
        var layer = event.layer;

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

see the source of http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html

Comment: can u please point to some example where I can get the coordinates of the polygon drawn and other operations

Comment: Draw plugin is creating layers that are documented here: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html. So when the Draw.Event.CREATED is called you can get all the values from layer. For example, if you draw a rectangle, it would be http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle